# Python 3.4.3 - How to save a itertools.permutations list usable?

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-itertools, human-readable

i've tried many solutions to my problem, but I haven't find a solution yet.

```
import itertools

a = ['car','boat','plane']
b = list(itertools.permutations(a,))
print(b)
```

It gives this list when printed.

```
[('car', 'boat', 'plane'), ('car', 'plane', 'boat'), ('boat', 'car', 'plane'), ('boat', 'plane', 'car'), ('plane', 'car', 'boat'), ('plane', 'boat', 'car')]
```

But this isn't usable to me. I need something like that:

```
car boat plane
car plane boat
boat car plane
boat plane car
plane car boat
plane boat car
```

Space between words, no comma and 1 per line.

This was just a sample, because I have phrases with 20 words each and I need to make this with each one.

Now, just a real sample what I have to do.

```
import itertools
'phrase What are you doing to this cat?'
a = ['what','are','you','doing','to','this','cat?']
b = list(itertools.permutations(a,))
print(b)
```

The result will be a monster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just unpack the tuples returned by `itertools.permutations(a,)` and a `for` loop:

```
import itertools
a = 'what are you doing to this cat?'.split()
for permutation in itertools.permutations(a,):
    print(*permutation)
```

Using `.split()` on the phrase will make it easier to change out the sentence.

Comment: You are awesome! This solve my problem and it's kind better than my code. Thanks.

Comment: @RafaelDias Great, glad I could help! Feel free to upvote/accept this answer.

Comment: you don't need to `join` to do it this way, you can just unpack it: `print(*permutation)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to produce that actual string you have described you can do it with two [`join`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) calls

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(r) for r in b)
```

The inner `join` concatenates the elements of each row with a `' '` separating them, the outer join then concatenates the rows with `'\n'` between them.  You can print the above directly or store it in a variable

Comment: This help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to format it a bit. Join the items with a space, and separate them with a newline.

```
print(*(' '.join(item) for item in itertools.permutations(a,)), sep='\n')
```

Alternatively:

```
for item in itertools.permutations(a,):
    print(' '.join(item))
```

Comment: This help me too! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`pprint.pprint` is often useful for inspecting data. It doesn't give you precisely the form you want in this case, but it does give a useful form.

Code:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

a = ['car','boat','plane']
b = list(itertools.permutations(a,))
pprint(b)
```

Result:

```
[('car', 'boat', 'plane'),
 ('car', 'plane', 'boat'),
 ('boat', 'car', 'plane'),
 ('boat', 'plane', 'car'),
 ('plane', 'car', 'boat'),
 ('plane', 'boat', 'car')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do a string join with ',' for each element of each record from itertools.permutations, then join each record together with '\n'.  Here it is with a generator expression:

```
import itertools

a = ['car','boat','plane']
b = itertools.permutations(a)
s = '\n'.join((','.join(permutation) for permutation in b))
print(s)
```